# Update source data or series ollection of a line chart

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to automate a *line chart* to include new rows of data in a column (from cell H11) using this VBA command:

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = _
    ActiveSheet.Range("H11").End(xlDown).Select
```

However I keep getting a:

> Run-time error '91':Object variable or With block variable not set

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: fixed formatting and the flow of information

Answer (score 0):

`.Select` is a method with no return value that changes the active selection. You can't assign it to `Values`. Either you select first and use `Selection`, or use something that returns a `Range`.

You can set the series Values range like this:

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = _
    Range("H11:H" & ActiveSheet.Range("H11").End(xlDown).Row)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.  However, I am still getting the same error :(

Comment: If it's still error 91 make sure the chart is selected before this line of code runs, `ActiveChart Is Nothing = False`. If it's error 1004 make sure your chart has a FullSeriesCollection, `ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection.Count > 0`

Comment: Hi dePatinkin.  Funny thing it works now with your original suggestion.  A BIG thank you to you for resolving this :)